# How to Contain a Bootstrap v5 Table in Main Div Content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have three Bootstrap v5 Tables that I want to be contained within the main body of my page. I am currently using Bootstrap Tabs in which the three different tables are contained separately. I have included one of my tables in my HTML example below.

My main body / content is defined by a `div` with the `class="container custom"`. I have set it to have a `height` of `100vh` in an attempt to have everything scale/fit within the viewport/browser height.

This is because I want to utilise the sticky table header and so the controls of the page aren't lost when the user scrolls to view certain table entries.

```
<div class="container custom flex-column">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col m-auto p-3"><h1 class="text-center">Company Directory</h1></div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-row p-3 mb-2" id="searchAndGo">
                <div class="col flex-fill btn-group-sm">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="searchQuery" size="20" placeholder="Search Names">
                        <select id="locations" class="_locations">
                        </select>
                        <select id="departments" class="_departments">
                        </select>
                        <div class="float-end btn-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" id="startSearch" onclick="startSearch()">GO</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="resetAll()">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                </div> 
                <div class="flex-row text-center">
                    <div class="dropdown" id="dropDownContainer">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Advanced Settings
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" id="radioSelect">
                            <li><span class="dropdown-item-text">Search by:</span></li>
                            <li><span class="dropdown-item"><input class="custom-control-input" id="any" type="radio" value="any" name="name" checked><label for="any">Any</label></span></li>                           
                            <li><span class="dropdown-item"><input class="custom-control-input" id="forename" type="radio" value="forename" name="name"><label for="forename">Forename</label></span></li>                           
                            <li><span class="dropdown-item"><input class="custom-control-input" id="surname" type="radio" value="surname" name="name"><label for="surname">Surname</label></span></li>                       
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <nav>
                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#nav-personnel" role="tab">Personnel</a>
                  <a class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#nav-departments" role="tab">Departments</a>
                  <a class="nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#nav-locations" role="tab">Locations</a>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="tab-content container" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active table-responsive" id="nav-personnel" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="personnel-tab">

                    <button id="addEntry" class="btn btn-success" onclick="openAddModal()">Add Personnel</button>


                        <table class='table table-striped table-hover' id="companyDirectoryPersonnel">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Location</th>
                                <th scope="col">Department</th>
                                <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>

                </div>
```

[image]

I want to use the Bootstrap `table-responsive` class to add a scroll bar and have the table header scroll with the table.

I've tried fiddling around with different `div`s around the `table` but none of them seems to want to adhere to the `container custom` `div` set height. I've tried using different `overflow` css rules on the main container and `div`s around the different `tables` and none of them worked in the way I had hoped. I even tried `inherit` on `height` but I think there's too many `div`s between the `table`s and the main body content `div`

Here is my current CSS that is used in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6hcc.png) above:

```
body {
    background-color: #85daf1;
}

.custom {
    display: flex;
    background-color: hsl(47, 100%, 93%);
    height: 100vh;
}
```